# Variance of Beta IV

Tags: matrix, covariance-matrix, instrumental-variables

I'm trying to calculate the variance of the Instrumental Variables (IV) estimator $${\hat \beta _{IV}} = {\left( {{Z^T}X} \right)^{ - 1}}{Z^T}y = \beta  + {\left( {{Z^T}X} \right)^{ - 1}}{Z^T}u$$ (or, more precisely, the variance-covariance matrix) but I can't get to the right result. I proceed as follows:$$
\begin{aligned} \operatorname{var} \left( {{{\hat \beta }_{IV}}} \right) &= E\left[ {\left( {{{\hat \beta }_{IV}} - \beta } \right){{\left( {{{\hat \beta }_{IV}} - \beta } \right)}^T}} \right] \\ &= E\left[ {\left( {{{\left( {{Z^T}X} \right)}^{ - 1}}{Z^T}u} \right){{\left( {{{\left( {{Z^T}X} \right)}^{ - 1}}{Z^T}u} \right)}^T}} \right] \\ &= {\sigma ^2}{\left( {{Z^T}X} \right)^{ - 1}}{Z^T}Z{\left( {{X^T}Z} \right)^{ - 1}} \end{aligned}
$$
which is not the desired result of ${\sigma ^2}{\left( {{Z^T}X} \right)^{ - 1}}{Z^T}Z{\left( {{Z^T}X} \right)^{ - 1}}$. Where is the mistake I'm doing? I just used basic matrix properties such as ${\left( {AB} \right)^T} = {B^T}{A^T}$ and ${\left( {{A^{ - 1}}} \right)^T} = {\left( {{A^T}} \right)^{ - 1}}$.

EDIT: Or it might be, in this case, since $Z$ only differs from $X$ by the endogenous columns, that both versions are actually equivalent?

Comment: Can you please provide the reference related to the "desired result"? Because the just-identified-IV variance I know, is the one you derived.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos For example [here](http://www.nyu.edu/classes/nbeck/q2/iv2slss.pdf) (slide 8) or [here](http://www3.grips.ac.jp/~yamanota/Lecture_Note_8_IV_and_2SLS.pdf) (page 11). Also, our teacher provided us with the same result so I thought that I was the one making the mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By an *appeal to mathematical rules* (and not to authority), the OP has derived the correct form of the variance of the IV-estimator in the just-identified case. But there are various sources over the web that say otherwise.

Well, they are wrong -possibly a left-over from the OLS case where the $X^TX$ matrix is symmetric. But the $Z^TX$ matrix is not symmetric. Somewhat more reliable references that certify the OP's result are [Greene ch. 5](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~wgreene/Text/econometricanalysis.htm)  or [Woolridge ch. 5](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/econometric-analysis-cross-section-and-panel-data).

Answer (score 0):

The formula you are using is from small sample properties of the Ordinary Least squares (OLS). Please note that Beta estimators got from Instrumental variables are biased in the small sample. You cannot get E(β^IV)=β since X is correlated with the error term "u" (endogeneity problem) and is no longer non-stochastic. Hence we cannot get the true expression of βiv from using the formula you are using.